# Correctly calculate the area beneath curve using trapz and simpson in python

Tags: python, area, integrate

I used np.trapz and scipy simps to calculate an area below a curve and noticed that I might not be doing it correctly. As an example below

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import simps


y = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y1= np.array([5,5,5,5,5])

print np.trapz(y,dx=1)
print simps(y,dx=1)
print np.trapz(y1,dx=1)
print simps(y1,dx=1)
```

These yield

```
12.0
12.0
20.0
20.0
```

But shouldn't they yeild 15 and 25 respectively? It seems like it between to small limits?

Comment: Why should they yield 15 and 25, respectively?

Comment: Well the python script may not because it is doing something other than I expect. But what I wanted was to get the full area beneath these points and if you the numbers you would get 15 and 25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have implicitly that `x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, remember that in programming almost everywhere and everything starts with `0`. Also, usually, upper limits are not inclusive.

For `y` that means a rectangle with vertices (0,0), (0,1), (4,0), and (4,1) plus a triangle with vertices (0,1), (4,5), and (4,1). The rectangle has an area of 4*1=4 and the triangle 4*4/2=8 totaling an area of 12.

For `y1` you have a rectangle with vertices (0,0), (0,5), (4,0), and (4,5), thus giving you and area of 20.

Comment: Yeah this is what I suspected. How do I include the upper limit and omit the 0?

I should stress, I am doing this for a large series of numbers in a different script.

Comment: You can define `x=[1,2,3,4,5]` and supply it to the function like `np.trapz(y,x)`

Comment: When I try this it yeilds the same result as before for both y and y1 in both traps and simps

Comment: Yes, sorry... it should have been something more like `np.trapz(y=[1,2,3,4,5,6], x=[0,1,2,3,4,5]` I missed the first `0`.